# Getting report FromDate ToDate

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtrareport

i have problem to get report between specific date. I wanna choose the date range for PurchaseDate but when i choose date range i saw all purchase date...

```
    private void barButtonItem1_ItemClick_1(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {

        XtraReport1 report = new XtraReport1();

        // Create a parameter and specify its name.
        Parameter param1 = new Parameter();
        param1.Name = "FromDate:";
        param1.Type = typeof(System.DateTime);

        param1.Description = "FromDate:";
        param1.Visible = true;

        Parameter param2 = new Parameter();
        param2.Name = "ToDate";
        param2.Type = typeof(System.DateTime);

        param2.Description = "ToDate: ";
        param2.Visible = true;

        report.Parameters.Add(param1);
        report.Parameters.Add(param2);

        report.FilterString = "[PurchaseDate] Between(?FromDate,?ToDate)";

        report.RequestParameters = false;

        ReportPrintTool pt = new ReportPrintTool(report);
        pt.AutoShowParametersPanel = true;
        pt.ShowPreviewDialog();
    }
```

Comment: Please, do not include a languge tag in a title unless it wouldn't made sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to set the value of the parameters.

Use this for yesterday:

```
param1.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
```

Until today:

```
param2.Value = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: user3198433: Did this answer help? Need more?

Comment: it does not work(( for example when i choose the from 21.01.2014 to 28.01.2014 i wanna see purchase dates between these days

Comment: Did you try to set the value like `report.ToDate.Value = ...`? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705080/how-to-pass-parameter-in-devexpress-report

Comment: @user3198433: what was the problem? If anything other, please add it as answer. If this post was useful, please mark the questions as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see where you set the  purchaseDate-Values. I think you have to set the Value-Properties of param1 and param2.

Comment: could you tell me please how can i set?

Comment: like in the answere form Patrick Hofman. I didn't see his answer as I wrote this one. :(